# Why React does not batch state updates for native apis or async functions, and how does React 18 solve that problem

Tags: reactjs

As we know, React batches all state updates happened in react-based functions, but for those happened in native APIs or async functions are not batched, I just want to know why React does not batch all state updates, is there any technical troubles causing it? And how does React 18 solve that problem?